# cypress - test data-testid by prefix

Tags: cypress

I want to test my page and verify there is no element with data-testid starts with "devonly-". for example, if cypress had wildcard it would look like that:

```
   cy.get('[data-testid=devonly-*]').should('not.exist');
```

Is any easy way to do it?